# CV(Curriculum vitae) Recommendation System guidance

Tags: scikit-learn, text-mining, recommender-system, tfidf

I am building a recommender system which matches people's CV with a vacancy.

So far, I used TF-IDF & Cosine Similarity to get a matching score between a vacancy and a candidate's CV.

I want to know whether there are any other approaches to create such a recommendation engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try word embeddings and unsupervised learning, for example:

> [medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-unsupervised-machine-learning-to-uncover-hidden-scientific-knowledge-6a3689e1c78d)

main idea is that similiar users will be in similiar clusters